# How to use send() method with Callback to return metadata?

Tags: java, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

I want to use callback method for Kafka Producer send() like this:

```
RecordMetadata recordmetadata = kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic,
                null, timestamp, key, message), this::onCompletion);

private RecordMetadata onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception exception) {
    if (exception == null) {
        return metadata;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I have the metadata or `null` returned by `onCompletion` method to be returned by send() method (since the method calling `send()` depends on it).

How can I make `send()` return metadata or `null` in combination with callback method?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation points that the send is asynchronous and the method will return immediately once the record has been stored in the buffer of records waiting to be sent. In order for it to work as you want you have to implement your own solution for it, for example using a global flag:

```
private RecordMetadata recordMetadata;
private boolean onCompletetionExecuted = false;

kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic,
                null, timestamp, key, auditorMessage), this::onCompletion);
while (!onCompletetionExecuted) {
    // waiting, would be good to have a fixed timeout
}
// after this point the value of recordMetadata is the one returned by onCompletion

private void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception exception) {
    if (exception == null) {
        recordMetadata = metadata;
    } else {
        recordMetadata = null;
    }
    onCompletetionExecuted = true;
}
```

This is far from elegant but it will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Remember send() works in async mode, so onCompletion will be executed in the new thread created by the send() call.

If you want metadata. You should just do this.

```
RecordMetadata recordmetadata = kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic,
            null, timestamp, key, message), this::onCompletion).get();
```

Remember, with this the call to send will wait for write/timeout before moving on.